# how to add source code to jar file using ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, jar, antbuilder

I want to add all my source code to jar file using ant while creating jar file from source code.

I want to have two files `1- myProject.jar  2-myproject_source.jar`

**What should i use and where should i put it?**

```
    <project name="myProject" >

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="./build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="./build/classes"/>          
    <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build/classes"/>                   
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="./build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar" basedir="./build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="DependencyFinder" value="main"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this just before your `<manifest>` line:

```
<fileset dir="./src" includes="**/*.java"/>
```

You can add mulitple `<fileset>` statements if you want.

Comment: when i run the build file, i don't get two files.

Comment: Ah, you didn't originally say you wanted them in separate jars.  In that case, create a second `<jar>` call to create the source also, like this:

`<jar destfile="./build/jar/DependencyFinder_source.jar" basedir="./build/source"/>`